# Fluid animation seems to disappear in some frames

Tags: modifiers, fluid-simulation

I wanted to create an commercial ad for a juice brand and was testing out fluid simulations.. for now my simulations seems to work properly but as I render the animation the fluid seems to disappear in some frames. I've added a boolean modifier to the fluid sim after baking it and it also has a animated material on it.[image][image]
(https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_wUjqWn82HtWmlwdEZyU0RXZkR3eEY4T3cxQ1ZkZjBqMGFB)